# RecognizerIntent not working; "missing extra calling_package"

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm having problems using the RecognizerIntent API on Android 2.2. When I call the API using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_VOICE_SEARCH);
```

which looks like it should work, the search popup says "Unknown problem" on the device and in the logs it states:

```
01-17 14:25:30.433: ERROR/RecognitionActivity(9118): ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent called incorrectly. Maybe you called startActivity, but you should have called startActivityForResult (or otherwise included a pending intent).
01-17 14:25:30.433: INFO/RecognitionControllerImpl(9118): startRecognition(#Intent;action=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH;launchFlags=0x800000;component=com.google.android.voicesearch/.IntentApiActivity;B.fullRecognitionResultsRequest=true;S.android.speech.extra.LANGUAGE_MODEL=free_form;end)
01-17 14:25:30.433: INFO/RecognitionControllerImpl(9118): State change: STARTING -> STARTING
01-17 14:25:30.443: ERROR/RecognitionControllerImpl(9118): required extra 'calling_package' missing in voice search intent
01-17 14:25:30.443: ERROR/RecognitionControllerImpl(9118): ERROR_CLIENT
01-17 14:25:30.443: ERROR/RecognitionControllerImpl(9118): ERROR_CLIENT
```

It looks like the problem is the missing "calling_package" extra; on the RecognizerIntent page it states that this extra is:

> The extra key used in an intent to the speech recognizer for voice
>   search. Not generally to be used by
>   developers. The system search dialog
>   uses this, for example, to set a
>   calling package for identification by
>   a voice search API. If this extra is
>   set by anyone but the system process,
>   it should be overridden by the voice
>   search implementation.

As far as I can tell, I don't need to override this extra, so why am I getting this error? How can I fix my code?

Comment: "anyone but the system process" - isn't yours NOT a system process which needs its own implementation?

Comment: Where are you calling startActivityForResult() from? Also, which device are you seeing this problem on? Finally, what are your Google Voice recognition settings?

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem. I was working on existing code that had android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the activity I was working on.  This will not work for speechrecognizer intent. I changed it to android:launchMode="standard".  Now let's see how it breaks the rest of my program :)

Answer (score 3):

Your original code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_VOICE_SEARCH);
```

Works correctly. I tested it on my device (HTC Desire), and also compared it to other open-source uses, by executing the following query in Google, and browsing the source code.

> RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH
>   site:code.google.com

One of the output lines in my logcat looks like this:

```
01-26 13:28:53.268: INFO/RecognitionController(1459): startRecognition(#Intent;action=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH;component=com.google.android.voicesearch/.IntentApiActivity;B.fullRecognitionResultsRequest=true;S.android.speech.extra.LANGUAGE_MODEL=web_search;S.calling_package=com.test;end)
```

Run a similar search with one of the built in apps (or downloaded ones), see that it works (and is not a device issue, etc.).

If that works correctly, take the code to a new test project, simply put those lines in the onCreate (Change the result constant to 0), and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the extra yourself?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra("calling_package","com.yourpackagename.YourActivityClassName");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_VOICE_SEARCH);
```

This is the approach used by [this code](http://jibjib.googlecode.com/svn-history/r635/trunk/android/src/com/sugree/jibjib/MessageListActivity.java) and is the suggested solution to a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693480/calling-android-speech-recognizerintent-api-results-in-connection-error-dialog-s).

Comment: Yeah. I tried with many different values, including context.getPackageName(), the package name hardcoded in, etc. None of it worked.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with the package layout you are using for your Activities and classes, as well as the values you have attempted to hardcode?